# Unable to access value of variable defined in DATA step

Tags: sas

I am trying to define a global "current year" variable I can use to index different tables in my database. For example, I have the following tables:

```
tb_2016
tb_2017
tb_2018
```

All with identical schema. For each year, I want to be able to dynamically reference previous years without hard-coding.

So I try this:

```
data _null_;
    v_curr_year = PUT(TODAY(), YEAR4.);
    v_last_year = v_curr_year - 1;
    PUT v_curr_year;
    PUT v_last_year;
run;
```

Which prints 2018 and 2017, as expected. However, when I try this:

```
PROC SQL;
    SELECT * FROM schema.tb_&v_curr_year.;
QUIT;
```

I get

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ...
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

How can I define this `v_curr_year` variable so I can dynamically reference years like this?

My attempts using `%LET v_last_year=YEAR(INTNX("year", sysdate, -1))` have been unsuccessful...

Comment: You need to use `%sysfunc()` around most functions in macro language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to assign macro variables within a data step you need to use `call symput()` or `call symputx()`. Also it's probably easier to just use the `year` function in the data step.

```
data _null_;
    v_curr_year = year(today());
    v_last_year = v_curr_year - 1;
    call symputx('v_curr_year',v_curr_year);
    call symputx('v_last_year',v_last_year);
run;
```

Now the two variables have been assigned as macro variables.

If you want to do this outside of a data step you can do the following.

```
%let v_curr_year = %sysfunc(year("&sysdate9"d));
%let v_last_year = %eval(&v_curr_year-1);
```

You need the `%eval` function to perform integer arithmetic in macro language and `%sysevalf` to perform floating point arithmetic.